# Store image in Firebase Storage and save metadata in Firebase Cloud Firestore (Beta)

Tags: javascript, firebase, metadata, firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage and save several certain metadata to the Firebase Cloud. 
I am coding in JavaScript.

Goal is to set also customised metadata to Firebase Cloud for example from a text input field which the user has to fill.

That's how I store images to the Firebase Storage:

```html
storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded', snapshot.totalBytes, 'bytes.');
        console.log(snapshot.metadata);
        var url = snapshot.downloadURL;
        console.log('File available at', url);
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        document.getElementById('linkbox').innerHTML = '<a href="' +  url + '">Click For File</a>';
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // [START onfailure]
        console.error('Upload failed:', error);
        // [END onfailure]
      });
      // [END oncomplete]
    }
```

I have no idea how to integrate in the upload function another task to write meta data to Firebase Cloud. 
Any help will be appreciated!

@eykjs @Sam Storie: Thanks for your help.
I changed my code. Right now, there is an error which I can't figure it out, whats wrong.
Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'selectedFile.name')

My code:

```html
var selectedFile;

function handleFileSelect(event) {
 //$(".upload-group").show();
 selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
};

function confirmUpload() {
 var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image',
  customMetadata: {
   'dogType': 'Lab',
   'title': $("#imgTitle").val(),
   'caption': $("#imgDesc").val()
  },
 };
 var uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref().child('dogImages/' + selectedFile.name).put(selectedFile, metadata);
  uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
    
 }, function(error) {
   
 } );

}
```

What is wrong with my selectedFile definition?
Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you could upload the data to Firestore after you finished the upload.

```
storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {
console.log('Uploaded', snapshot.totalBytes, 'bytes.');

let db = firebase.firestore();
let dbRef = db.collection("images").doc(file.name);

let setData = dbRef.set({
    //yourdata here
    downloadURl: snapshot.downloadURL
}).then( () => {
    console.log("Data stored in Firestore!");
});

// your actions
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're after this should easily be done with Firebase functions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions

You can trigger a function when something in storage changes, and thus easily write data to either the realtime database, or the new(er) Firestore database.

Here's a simple snippet from the page I referenced to see what this might look like:

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-image-upload-with-progress-in-firestore-and-firestorage-tutorial-by-application/)**

Image Upload in **Firestore** and saving meta info on **Cloud Storage**

[image]

```
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...
...
...

// The main task
this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, { customMetadata });

// Get file progress percentage
this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(

  finalize(() => {
    // Get uploaded file storage path
    this.UploadedFileURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();

    this.UploadedFileURL.subscribe(resp=>{
      this.addImagetoDB({
        name: file.name,
        filepath: resp,
        size: this.fileSize
      });
      this.isUploading = false;
      this.isUploaded = true;
    },error=>{
      console.error(error);
    })
  }),
  tap(snap => {
      this.fileSize = snap.totalBytes;
  })
)
```